# How to determine the destructive efficiency of my city-bombing algorithm?

Tags: c, algorithm

Here is the problem I want to solve in C:

> #### Problem
>
> A war has started between two rival countries A and B. Country A wants to destroy the Capital city of B through aerial bombing. But due to the sudden outbreak of war, the ammunition reserves are low on both sides. Due to less quantity of ammunition, fighter pilot Jeff has been asked to carry the exact number of bombs that are required to destroy the whole city. Each bomb can be dropped on a building only.
>
> Capital of country B is a one dimensional city with n buildings, where each building (i) is located at some x(i) on the x-axis. Jeff has to destroy every building in the city. Each bomb has a destructive range k, meaning it can destroy everything at a distance ≤ k units away from its point of impact.
>
> Now given a map of the city and the range k of the bomb, Jeff wants you to find the minimum number of bombs he needs to destroy the whole city(each building must be in the destructive range of at least one bomb).
>
> #### Input
>
> The first line contains two space-separated integers n(number of buildings in the city) and k(range of destruction of each bomb).
> The second line contains n space-separated integers, depicting the location of buildings on the x-axis.
>
> #### Output
>
> Print a single integer denoting the minimum number of bombs required to destroy the city.

#### Constraints

```
1 ≤ n,k ≤ 10^5
1 ≤ x ≤ 10^5
```

#### Sample Input

```
4 2
1 2 3 4
```

#### Sample Output

```
1
```

[Link to the question.](https://code.dcoder.tech/challenges/algoyo/5cd74bf81681076686ea2ec3/depleting-ammunition)

> Question can also be found at: **code.dcoder.tech > challenges > hard > depleting ammunition**

---

### My Solution

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Variables named according to the problem
 * n         - number of buildings
 * k         - range of bombs
 * buildings - Array containing the integer
 *             coordinates of the buildings
 */
int n, k, *buildings;

void getInput(void);
int isBuilding(int);
int nextBuilding(int);
int lastBuilding(int);

int main(void) {
 getInput();
 int bombs = 0;
 /* Loops through the x cordinates from building 1 to n
  * i - indicates the x coordinate where jeff is
  * j - indicates the bombed area
  * r - indicates the bomb range
  */
 for (int i = buildings[0], j = (buildings[0] - 1), r = k; i <= buildings[n - 1] || j < buildings[n - 1]; i++, r--) {
  /* When joel leaves bomb range coordinates behind */
  if (r == 0) {
   /* Bomb is only dropped on a building */
   while (!isBuilding(i))
    i--;
   /* Increment bombed area (back, position and front)*/
   j = i + k;
   bombs++;
   r = k + 1; // +1 because the loop makes r--
   /* next building beyond range
    * +1 because we need to leave all bombed area behind
    */
   i = nextBuilding(i + k + 1);
   /* if no building */
   if (i == 0)
    break;
   else
    i--; // the loop will make i++
  }
 }
 printf("%d\n", bombs);
 return 0;
}

/* Ascending comparison for qsort */
int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
 const int *aa = a;
 const int *bb = b;
 return (*aa > *bb) - (*aa < *bb);
}

/* Gets input for n, k and buildings,
 * and sorts buildings
 */
void getInput(void) {
 if (scanf("%d %d", &n, &k) != 2) {
  fprintf(stderr, "input error\n");
  return;
 }
 buildings = calloc(sizeof *buildings, n);
 if (!buildings) {
  fprintf(stderr, "allocation error\n");
  return;
 }
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  if (scanf("%d", &buildings[i]) != 1) {
   fprintf(stderr, "input error\n");
   return;
  }
 }
 qsort(buildings, n, sizeof *buildings, compare);
}

/* Returns 1 if it is a building,
 *  0 otherwise
 */
int isBuilding(int p) {
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  if (buildings[i] == p)
   return 1;
 }
 return 0;
}

/* Returns position of next building greater or equal to p,
 * 0 if none available
 */
int nextBuilding(int p) {
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  if (buildings[i] >= p)
   return buildings[i];
 }
 return 0;
}

/* Returns position of last building less or equal to p
 * 0 if none available
 */
int lastBuilding(int p) {
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  if (buildings[i] == p)
   return buildings[i];
  else if (buildings[i] > p)
   return buildings[--i];
 }
 return 0;
}
```

#### Explanation

I take a more direct approach the problem since trying to find a formular seemed impossible.

In **main** I use `i` as Jeff's position and he moves `k` (bomb range) distance ahead then place a bomb there if there exists a building at that point, or move back to the last building. (The question explicitly mentions that a bomb can only be placed at a building).

Then I move `i` to the next unbombed building and repeat the above process.

The condition `j < n` is for when there are buildings left but `i <= buildings[n - 1]` cannot be met (`i` has exceeded the last building).

### Issue

The code seems to be working well on my end.

I have tested with various input (some shown below) besides the one in the question and got the desired output.

```
Input:
6 2
1 2 3 4 5 6
Output: 2

Input:
10 2
2 3 8 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
Output: 4
```

**Although when I submit the problem, all tests fail**.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `buildings` points to the local array `temp` in `getInput`. That array goes out of scope when the function returns.

Comment: @BoP Thanks for the correction, but it seems not to resolve the issue. All the tests still fail. I have updated the question (with the new solution).

Comment: Do not use global variables, ever.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I edited the question and added the new code. Its labelled update at the top.

Comment: There's probably some clever formula you need to find or figure out. It looks of a similar type to the 'House Robber' problem. Probablly, MinBombs_k(n) = some function of MinBombs_k(n-1) and x_n. The link to the question isn't currently working.

Comment: @SimonGoater I have thought so, but i failed to figure out the formular. Also the problem is copied and pasted from link, but you can find it at https://code.dcoder.tech/ > challenges > hard > depleting ammunition

Comment: "The tests fail" is not enough to describe the acceptance criteria on this page. Could you be more specific about what a successful solution would look like?

Comment: [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/dh18vKoaP) is a failed test for you. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/fddPTfcTf) is another one.

Comment: Do you account for blast radius? Presumably the idea is that some buildings are within blast radius of each other so you can use Pythagoras' formula to identify that you only need one bomb between multiple buildings.

Comment: @SmellyCat Yes. I account for that by incrementing `i` by `k` (range of bomb) after placing the bomb.

Comment: @SmellyCat  The Pythagoras' formula in one dimension is rather simple.

Comment: @SmellyCat Do you mind providing an answer using that, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are Some problems:

- In function `getInput()`, you store a pointer to a local array `temp` into the global variable `buildings`: `buildings = temp;`.

  Reading from the array pointed to by `building` after `getInput()` returns has undefined behavior.  You should instead allocate memory with `malloc` or `calloc`.
- Also you make the assumption that the building offsets are input in ascending order, but there is no such constraint expressed in the assignment. You might want to sort the array during or after input.
- `isBuilding(0)` returns `0` in all cases, so there is no way to test if there is a building at offset `0`. This should not be a problem if the constraint `x >= 1` is verified but, for consistency, `isBuilding(p)` should return `1` if a building is found with offset `p`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int compare_ints(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const int *aa = a;
    const int *bb = b;
    return (*aa > *bb) - (*aa < *bb);
}

/* Gets input for n, k and buildings */
void getInput(void) {
    if (scanf("%d %d", &n, &k) != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "input error\n");
        return;
    }
    buildings = calloc(sizeof *buildings, n);
    if (!buildings) {
        fprintf(stderr, "allocation error\n");
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &buildings[i]) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "input error\n");
            return;
        }
    }
    qsort(buildings, n, sizeof *buildings, compare_ints);
}

/* Returns 1 if it is a building, 0 otherwise */
int isBuilding(int p) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (buildings[i] == p)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have added the code accordingly. It seems that this did not resolve the issue. For some reason, all the tests are failing, yet my own tests pass. Thanks

Comment: @Jore your code still doesn't sort the input.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI now that you speak of it. The input could be sorted. Let me try that

Comment: @Jore: I updated the answer with efficient sorting code.

Comment: Thank you for the great feedback, but i it still wont work. I have edited the code in the question to reflect your changes.

Comment: Turns out it is a bug in the website where i submit that doesnt do it well for **C** and re writing the solution in java solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**
I missed an important condition that a bomb can be only dropped on a building. It makes the simplistic approach of this answer invalid.

**EDIT 2**
On the second though the problem with the condition doesn't seem much different. Here is an updated and commented main loop:

```
qsort(buildings, n, sizeof(*buildings), compare_int);
int n_bombs = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n;)
{
    // What is the first building that if we drop on it
    // we won't destroy this building?
    int drop = i;
    while (drop < n && buildings[drop] - buildings[i] <= k) 
      ++drop;
    // Back up by one building and drop a bomb on it
    --drop;
    ++n_bombs;

    // What is the first building that was not destroyed?
    int j = drop;
    while (j < n && buildings[j] - buildings[drop] <= k)
      ++j;
    
    // It will be our next building to consider
    i = j;
}
```

It computes 4 bombs for 2 3 4 7 10 11 12 13 14 15 as requested. Didn't test it further.

This loop has some repetitive code so a function is in order. If we introduce `nextBuilding`:

```
int nextBuilding (int* buildings, int current, int radius, int total)
{
    int next = current;
    while (next < total && buildings[next] - buildings[current] <= radius)
      ++next;
    --next;
    return next;
}
```

the loop compresses to

```
for (int i = 0; i < n;)
{
    int drop = nextBuilding(buildings, i, k, n);
    ++n_bombs;
    i = nextBuilding(buildings, drop, k, n) + 1;
}
```

**Original invalid answer follows**
Your logic in the main loop is rather hard to follow. This is how it could look like, assuming sorted input (warning, untested code).

```
qsort(buildings, n, sizeof(*buildings), compare_int);
int n_bombs = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n;)
{
  ++n_bombs;
  int last_destroyed_x = buildings[i] + 2*k;  // edit: was 2*k + 1
  while (i < n && buildings[i] <= last_destroyed_x)
    ++i;
}
```

There is no need for helper functions like `isBuilding` or `nextBuilding`.

Comment: Let me try this solution. Thanks

Comment: Also i have added comments to the code in the question. I use the more direct approach where joel moves as `i` and drops the bombs as the i increaseas.

Comment: This solution does not work and i think here is why. Your code assumes that every coordinate will have a building. (not true)

Comment: Assume somerhing like _ 2 3 4 _ _ 7 _ _ 10 11 12 13 14 15 where the dashes are empty coordinates and the answer with range (k) 2 is 4 i.e bombs placed at 4, 7, 12, and 15

Comment: "Your code assumes that every coordinate will have a building" No it does not. I didn't test this code so it may or may not work, but something very similar to it should work.

Comment: In your example the answer is 3, not 4 (drops at 4, 9 and 14). My code gives 2 because of an off by one error. Change `2*k + 1` to `2*k` and it will be correct.

Comment: By dropping at 9, did you consider that bombs can only be dropped on buildings from the question?

Comment: @Jore see update

Comment: This code works (at least for the tests i have done) and it still **fails all the tests on submission**

Comment: I have finally figured out the problem. It is somewhere with the website, not our code. I have **re written your code in java** and **all the tests have passed.**